# Installing maven problems

Tags: java, maven

I have just installed Maven. I execute in a CMD console `mvn -version`, it works.

```
C:\>cd apache-maven-3.3.3

C:\apache-maven-3.3.3>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:3
7+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

When I try to execute command `c:\mvn -version` I receive a list with the possible commands of `java`.

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Add to C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\ to path

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have not set the PATH variable in your windows system.

Navigate to Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables

> Copy  "C:{path_to_maven}\bin" and append it to your 'Path'
>   environment variable.

And Also it is recommended that you set the

> M2_HOME

in the User Variables Section to "C:{path_to_maven}\" so that you do not run into troubles in the future

[If you need more details, go to the official page of maven by clicking on this link.](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `M2_HOME` variable in the Windows environment, and point it to your Maven folder. Update PATH variable, append Maven bin folder: `%M2_HOME%\bin`, so that you can run the Maven’s command everywhere.